# React with strapi implement

Tags: next.js, strapi

I am using Strapi with the [next js](https://strapi.io/blog/strapi-next-authentication). The code below is not rendering the page with Internet Explorer version 11. Can you please suggest what might be the issue?

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Strapi from "strapi-sdk-javascript/build/main";
```

Comment: At the moment I suggest you not to use the sdk but axios instead. You can install the documentation plugin directly from the marketplace in your administration panel to quickly notice your endpoint

Comment: can it be rendered even if you do not have the render function or the return of the class you want to be rendered?

Answer (score 1):

From the readme:

> ⚠️ This package not up to date and maintained ⚠️
> https://github.com/strapi/strapi-sdk-javascript

So, I don't think use that SDK is a good decision right now.
Move to axios, like suggest the comment or any good library you feel fine to consume de HTTP/graphQL API.